# How do I reset a remote branch in Visual Studio 19

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019, git-reset

I had to reset the git branch I was working on to a previous commit.  This only reset my local branch apparently. After making changes in my development environment I was unable to push them because the commit I had reset from locally still exists on the remote branch.  I followed the steps to force push my local branch:

1. In Team Explorer, Settings, checked the box to enable push --force.
2. In Branches, I right-clicked on my (active) branch and selected Push.
3. I got the warning "This branch is behind its remote counterpart..." and I clicked Yes to proceed.

[screenshot of git warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2don.png)

4. It pushed the branch but then failed.  The error in the Output window is:

```
Error: failed to push some refs to 'myrepourl'
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: PushCommand.ExecutePushCommand
```

I'm seeing others have had this issue and resolved it by pulling the remote changes.  I would like to overwrite the remote changes however. Is this possible in Team Explorer? Or does this have to be done through the git cli?

Comment: What exactly were the steps you followed to force push?

Comment: To overwrite the remote changes in Team Explorer open tab Team Explorer->Parameters->Global. And check the flag "push --forse".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the remote has work that you don't have locally, did you try doing a "git fetch"?  I'm not familiar with the GUI in VS but if you open a command prompt and navigate to the tracked folder, you can execute the two following statements:

```
git fetch
git pull
```

git fetch will pull down the structure
git pull will download any missing files you don't have locally.

Edit...

```
git commit -a -m "update message goes here"
git push
```

Comment: My problem is I want to overwrite the remote changes.

Comment: In that case you want to commit and push.  I have updated the answer for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @DataGuy.  I opened the git command window, used `git push -f` and that did it.  I'll interpret your answer as "Yes you have to use git command line." and mark this as answer though this question is still closed pending my edits which I put in earlier.